# Background video does not play on mobile?

Tags: css, html, forms, video, mobile

I've made a landing page where video plays at the background of a form.
It's working fine on desktops but I checked on my Android device using Chrome, the background video does not play on it.

Could anyone help me to fix the issue.

Here is the link to my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamshedAlamQureshi/xpnus1jv/1/).

**HTML:**

```
   <p>
<video autoplay="" id="video" loop=""><source src="http://www.mygreencity.in/Enquiry.mp4" type="video/webm" /> <source src="Enquiry.mp4" type="video/mp4" /></video>
</p>  

<form action="" class="form" method="post">


<p><input name="enq_name" placeholder="Full Name" required="" type="text" autocomplete="off" alt="Full Name" title="Full Name"/></p>

<p><input name="enq_mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number" required="" type="number" autocomplete="off" alt="Number" title="Number"/></p>

<p><input name="enq_email" placeholder="Email" required="" type="email" autocomplete="off" alt="Email ID" title="Email ID"/></p>
<input class="button button-block" name="enq_submit" type="submit" value="Go To Site" alt="Go To Site" title="Go To Site"/></form>
```

**CSS:**

```
    *, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #1ab188;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
          transition: .5s ease;
}
a:hover {
  color: #179b77;
}

.form {
  background: rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.9);
  padding: 40px;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 80px auto;

  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 4px rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.3);
}


h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0 0 40px;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(6px);
      -ms-transform: translateY(6px);
          transform: translateY(6px);
  left: 13px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
          transition: all 0.25s ease;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 22px;
}

input, textarea {

  font-size: 22px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #a0b3b0;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-transition: border-color .25s ease, box-shadow .25s ease;
          transition: border-color .25s ease, box-shadow .25s ease;
}
input:focus, textarea:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border-color: #1ab188;
}

textarea {
  border: 2px solid #a0b3b0;
  resize: vertical;
}


.button {
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 15px 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  background: #1ab188;
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
          transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.button:hover, .button:focus {
  background: #179b77;
}

.button-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.forgot {
  margin-top: -20px;
  text-align: right;
}

p {
margin-bottom: 40px;
}


video { 
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  background: #fff;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: 1s opacity;
}

div{
margin:20px;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}

input[type=number] {
-moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

Comment: Auto play video is disabled on Chrome for Android as well as most mobile platforms.

Answer (score 13):

You need a couple more attributes for your video element

```
<video autoplay loop muted playsinline id="video-background" poster="images/poster.jpg">
```

Safari and Chrome for mobile made changes on how video on mobile acts. By default, it can only autoplay when the video is **muted**. But for webkit/iOs you also need a second attribute; **playsinline**. This attribute makes it so that it plays inline, rather than jumping to fullscreen video.

Also make sure your mobile devices are not running in Low Power Mode if you’re targeting iOS 11. If you’re on Chrome For Android, Data Saver mode will also prevent auto play and thus won't show the video. There's not anyway around this.

Comment: thank you --- "autoplay loop muted playsinline" worked

Comment: Works for me as well

Comment: And for me too! Thank you!

Comment: You are the man for pointing out the issue with Low Power Mode!!! Thank you.

Comment: I tried it today, and it works for me.

Comment: Works like a charm. Also, this attribute should be camelCase in react; `playsInline`

Answer (score 4):

You should have a look on this kind of [jQuery plugin](http://syddev.com/jquery.videoBG/).

Otherwise, instead of only having a `.mp4` format, you should provide some `.webm` and `.ogv` formats alternatives as well to have a **better compatibility** over browsers and devices.
You should also have a "fallback" image like the `poster="videos/poster.png"` in the following example. In case none of those format would works with the used browser / platform, this image is displayed instead of the video.

You will have to **convert your video** into `.webm` and `.ogv`.

As I'm still myself looking for a good converting tool *(no extra ugly banner after the convert and stuff)*, I couldn't give you some advice about this.

```
<video id="bgVideo" autoplay poster="videos/poster.png">
    <source src="http://www.mygreencity.in/Enquiry.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    <source src="http://www.mygreencity.in/Enquiry.webm" type="video/webm"/>
    <source src="http://www.mygreencity.in/Enquiry.ogv" type="video/ogg"/>    
</video>
```

Good Luck'

Comment: my issue was that mp4s wouldnt play on android so I had to use webm

Answer (score 4):

CSS:

```
#section-video video {
   display: block; 
}
```

give the diplay block instead of none in the corresponding css file.

Comment: this was the solution for me :)