# autoPlay background video doesn't render on mobile

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a react website, and i'm using a video background for the homepage, it works perfectly in the desktop version but the video doesn't render at all on mobile

The video tag already contains the autoPlay and mute attributes, I added playsInline but still nothing happens

here is the html code:

```html
<header className="v-header container">
                <div className="fullscreen-video-wrap">
                    <video src={code} autoPlay muted loop playsInline type="video/mp4"></video>
                </div>
                <div className="header-overlay"></div>
                <div className="header-content text-md-center">
                    <h1>Night'Art+</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id temporibus perferendis necessitatibus numquam amet impedit explicabo? Debitis quasi ullam aperiam!</p>
                    <Button inverted basic size='massive'>Join us</Button>
                </div>
            </header>
```

and the css code:

```css
  .v-header{
    height:100vh;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    color:#fff;
  }

  .container{
    max-width:960px;
    padding-left:1rem;
    padding-right:1rem;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
  }

  .fullscreen-video-wrap{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    overflow:hidden;
  }

  .fullscreen-video-wrap video{
    min-height:100%;
    min-width:100%;
  }

  .header-overlay{
    height:100vh;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100vw;
    z-index:1;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #4300ab, #ff0a6c);
    opacity:0.7;
  }

  .header-content{
    z-index:2;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .header-content h1{
    font-size:50px;
    margin-bottom:0;
  }

  .header-content p{
    font-size:1.5rem;
    display:block;
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Background video does not play on mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31588115/background-video-does-not-play-on-mobile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this site](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/autoplay), mobile devices needs to meet some criteria to allow autoplay (video size, user gestures, audio track, etc.). Most browsers takes in mind users data consumption. More info [here](https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/). If you provide me a link and your device specs, I can research a bit more.

Comment: Here is the repo for my code https://gitlab.com/Seimitsu/nightart/tree/master/src/pages/Homepage. And the link for the website nightart.netlify.com

Comment: I read more about this, and cloned and tested your code, it seems to be a react issue, im still looking for a working example to send you, but you can read it too from here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6544

this is a working gist: https://gist.github.com/diuis/fc1c2f0e255538cda397c5a6b669c9bf

Comment: @FahmauouiYasser I found a problem with your video, I've managed to autoplay a bigger file in my iPhone 6, so inspecting your file show that the codec is 'av01', you need to convert that video to AAC, H.264. I converted the file for you, you can test it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IhCNgNcHu9IXXPoxcZj84GrBbbWv4U7R/view?usp=sharing